# Remove multiple items from Immutable List in one shot

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

Given this:

```
state = Immutable.fromJS({
  selectedTrackIds: ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'],
});
```

Is there a way to get a new state where 'foo' and 'baz' are removed from `selectedTrackIds`, using a single statement (using only Immutable and plain JS)? Or will I just have to use lodash?

```
return state.set('selectedTrackIds', Immutable.fromJS(_.difference(
  state.get('selectedTrackIds').toJSON(), ['foo', 'baz']
)));
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `filter` to remove the items you don't want:

```
return state.set('selectedTrackIds',
  state.get('selectedTrackIds').filter(function(x) {
    return ['foo', 'baz'].indexOf(x) < 0; // false return value => remove from list
  })
);
```

Or combine it with `map`, and some ES6 syntax:

```
state.map(x => x.filter(y => ['foo', 'baz'].indexOf(y) < 0))
```

(`filter` and `map` are standard JS, and Immutable provides its own implementations that work directly with Immutable collections)

Comment: Nice! I was just wondering if there was something built into Immutable that I was missing.